# is it possible to change a string type column to array type column before using explode function in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I would like to know if it is possible change the "data" column which is String type into array type, but with a comma between numbers.

```
#+----------+---------------------+------------+
#|date      |month                |data        |
#+----------+---------------------+------------+
#|2015      |08                   |01001111    |
#|2016      |06                   |011111101   |
#|2017      |02                   |0101011100  |
#|2018      |11                   |01101111    |
#+----------+---------------------+------------+
```

I need the next:

```
#+----------+---------------------+------------------------+
#|date      |month                |data                    |
#+----------+---------------------+------------------------+
#|2015      |08                   | [0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1]      |
#|2016      |06                   | [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1]    |
#|2017      |02                   | [0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0]  |
#|2018      |11                   | [0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1]      |
#+----------+---------------------+------------------------+
```

The reason why I need this change is because I have to use posexplode function, and it works with arrays.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with custom function(UDF):

```
df = df.withColumn("data", F.udf(lambda x: x.split(','))('data'))
```

Comment: But if I run the code above, I will just have the same String type column with separated characters with commas, isn't? And I need an array type for the posexplode function. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @Telec20, no you will have an Array type not a String, the udf return an list which is an Array type in spark api. It works as you want :-)

Comment: @Telec20 is the question still open?